# Attempting to build C# web project. Getting Minor Version Mismatch on on build

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following information when I build a Web project in C#.

This is different from the many solutions here I have checked because `System.Web.Cors` is prebundled with the build, and cannot be modified via Nuget Package Manager.

I have been researching this for several weeks. Does anybody have an idea where to start

```
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = ******
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = *****
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Cors, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\*****\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/******/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/11765218/51009fcd/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/******/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/11765218/51009fcd/System.Web.Cors/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/**/src/**/bin/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

UPDATE: I've identified that the lowest package number is in fact 5.0.0. updating the bindingRedirect does not seem to help. More interestingly however, I've seen a new employee download this project clean and run it instantaneously. After talking with other employees it seems the problem is my machine. I've recloned the repo serveral times. So this repo does work on other machines, so I'm less likely to believe the issue is with the project.

Comment: It's possible one of your other dependencies has already "required" an older version version of that assembly; this blog post sums it up pretty well IMO:  https://chiragrupani.medium.com/how-to-resolve-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-and-why-this-cf8d48d788eb .  The upshot is you have to identify which version you need to end up with and use a bindingRedirect in your config

Comment: So whats strange is there is a bindingRedirect in that element already as follows.

```<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```
The log here doesnt ever say `Download was successful` like the article does. Do you think that has something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe; it does look like it's searching "known repos" for a dll to download, but I *think* it actually fails with a different error if it can't find it.  You may be able to change the "newVersion" to match, if you can determine what's the lowest-numbered release that can be supported by all your dependencies.  Either way I think your next best step is probably to determine what other library is depending on the different/older version, so you have both "halves" of the problem visible at the same time.

Comment: So I have some updates. I've identified that the lowest package number is in fact 5.0.0. updating the bindingRedirect does not seem to help.

More interestingly however, I've seen a new employee download this project clean and run it instantaneously. After talking with other employees it seems the problem is my machine. I've recloned the repo serveral times. In your expertise could the nature of this problem be environmental? If so where would be a good place to look?